# gdb pretty printers is not working inside visual studio code for c++

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, pretty-print

I followed [this](https://undo.io/resources/gdb-watchpoint/here-quick-way-pretty-print-structures-gdb/) tutorial on pretty printing for gdb c++ objects
it's working fine when tried from the terminal but inside vscode session it shows the normal output

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/AML_example",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "miDebuggerArgs": "-x ${workspaceFolder}/pretty_printers.py",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Build"
        }

    ]
}
```

pretty_printers.py:

```
import gdb 

class Matrix33Printer:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        m11 = self.val['m11']
        m12 = self.val['m12']
        m13 = self.val['m13']
        m21 = self.val['m21']
        m22 = self.val['m22']
        m23 = self.val['m23']
        m31 = self.val['m31']
        m32 = self.val['m32']
        m33 = self.val['m33']
        return '\n[{} {} {}]\n[{} {} {}]\n[{} {} {}]'.format(m11, m12, m13, m21, m22, m23, m31, m32, m33)

class Vector3Printer:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        x = self.val['x']
        y = self.val['y']
        z = self.val['z']
        return '[{}, {}, {}]'.format(x, y, z)

def my_pretty_printers(val):
    if str(val.type) == 'AML::Matrix33': 
        return Matrix33Printer(val)
    if str(val.type) == 'AML::Vector3': 
        return Vector3Printer(val)
    return None

gdb.pretty_printers.append(my_pretty_printers)
```

gdb output from terminal

```
Breakpoint 1, AML::normalizeDCM (dcm=...) at AML/DCM.cpp:46
46              void normalizeDCM(Matrix33 &dcm){
(gdb) p dcm
$1 = (AML::Matrix33 &) @0x7fffffffdf40:
[1 0 0]
[0 1 0.01]
[0 -0.01 1]
```

and finally this is the output from the debug console in vs code and the inline values, I suspected it's not reading the script file from the `launch.json` "miDebuggerArgs"  but you can see in the final output I tried to source the python script again from the console but didn't work

I also verified that gdb.pretty_printers has my_pretty_printers reference inside it

```
-exec python print(gdb.pretty_printers)
[<gdb.printing.RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter object at 0x7fe69a343af0>, <function my_pretty_printers at 0x7fe69ac8bd90>]
```

- How can I make pretty printing work inside visual studio code debug console and inline values

EDIT: I printed the val.type in the my_pretty_printers functions and found that it prints more type qualifier like `const AML::Matrix33` instead of just `AML::Matrix33` like in the terminal
so I modified the function to try .**contains** instead of == like so:

```
def my_pretty_printers(val):
    if str(val.type).__contains__('AML::Matrix33'): 
        return Matrix33Printer(val)
    if str(val.type).__contains__('AML::Vector3'): 
        return Vector3Printer(val)
    #print(val.type)
    return None
```

don't know why the `val.type` behaviour is different from the terminal but it's working fine now

```
-exec source ../pretty_printers.py
-exec p dcm
$1 = (const AML::Matrix33 &) @0x7fffffffdd80: {{data = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {m11 = 1, m12 = 0, m13 = 0, m21 = 0, m22 = 1, m23 = 0, m31 = 0, m32 = 0, m33 = 1}}}
```

Comment: Can you try to add some debug statements to `my_pretty_printers` to see if it's ever called, and if yes, with what `val.type`?

Comment: @ssbssa I already tried val.type from terminal and it only showed the types I wrote in the function so didn't try to do it again from vscode but for some reason `val.type` is different in vs code with extra type qualifiers 
I edited the question with the modified function it's working fine for now

thanks for the hint

Comment: Well, it says that wherever you tried it in vscode that `dcm` was a const reference, but in `normalizeDCM`, it was a normal reference. So you need to be aware of that. [`gdb.types.get_basic_type(val.type)`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdb_002etypes.html) might be helpful.

Comment: @ssbssa
ah yes that was the problem `get_basic_type` and `__contains__` both were working fine thanks